# Get field value in viewer.js file (from pdf.js)

Tags: 7, javascript

I created PDF files protected with password. They are uploaded to Drupal and the password is saved in a field `pdf_password` in Drupal.

I would like the PDF to open them with pdf.js without having to ask for the password. For this I need to get the value of the field password `pdf_password` in the file libraries/pdf.js/web/viewer.js: instead of 123 to get the value of the field password pdf_password :

```
parameters.password = '123';
```

(the pdf.js is pdf.js project by Mozilla)

Comment: You might as well remove the password if you're going to make it available to anyone using the browser

Comment: I won't have it available to the public I want the pdf to open in the page but should be password protected when downloaded

Comment: You realise that any slightly-competent user would be able to just look at your javascript file and get the password though, right?

Comment: that is why I don't want to write there the password but <?php $pass= field_get_items('node', $node, $pdf_password); ?>and in the javascript file: <script type="text/javascript"> parameters.password = '<?php print $pass?>'; </script>

Comment: Yep, which anyone will be able to read, because it’s in a JavaScript file

Comment: If we write parameters.password = '<?php print $pass?>'; </script> how can you tell what is the password? noone could see here the value of $pass

Comment: Literally by reading it. If your JS code can read it, then a human can also read it, by definition.

Comment: you say that if javascript has access to it so anyone can get access to it? in the javascript file itself it won't be written but will just call for the value how can anyone has access to it?

Comment: It doesn't “call” anything. By the time the file is sent to the requester, the PHP has executed, and the file contains whatever PHP told it to write. PHP is not processed on-the-fly inside a browser. It’s easy to test, just try it and see what happens

Comment: If someone will look then at the javascript file he will see then instead of  parameters.password = '<?php print $pass?>';  parameters.password = 'password';?

Comment: Of course :) if that’s news to you, and with the greatest respect, you need to do a bit of learning about web fundamentals before doing anything that involves passwords

Comment: Thank you Do you have any other idea how i could go about it? Pdf should open on the website without having to ask the password but should be password protected when downloaded?

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible using javascript. A different approach would be to use PHP to open the protected PDF, convert it to HTML, then serve that or embed it via an iframe or something. The password would only be used in PHP, so not exposed to the client, but if the PDF was downloaded directly it would still have protection. The thing to realise is that the file has to be decrypted server side, not client side, if you want the password to remain safe

Comment: [This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) would probably be a useful one to read to get an idea of the general principles that govern server vs client side

Comment: Do you think I could do it with ajax?